# Excluding validation on certain cases alone through annotations

Tags: java, validation, annotations

I am using a common entity called Amount.java in multiple places like Order.java, Shipping.java to indicate order amount, shipping amount etc.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "currency_code", "value" })
public class Amount {

@JsonProperty("currency_code")
@Length(max = 3, message = "field.length.max")
@NotEmpty(message = "field.nonEmpty")
@CurrencyCode
private String currencyCode;

@JsonProperty("value")
@JsonSerialize(using = NumberSerializer.class, include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@NotNull(message = "field.nonNull")
@Digits(integer = 6, fraction = 2, message = "field.amount.format")
@DecimalMin(value = "0.01", message = "field.number.positive")
private BigDecimal value;
}
```

If you see there is a restriction over value field which allows only positive amount to be passed. While this is the case for most of the scenarios, I've encountered a different case where in say MyNewEntity.java I am reusing the Amount.java and for MyNewEntity.java alone I should allow negative values also.

Is there a simple way to do this or some kind of exclusion mechanism can be employed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **validation groups** feature. Here is the [nice article](http://www.jroller.com/eyallupu/entry/jsr_303_beans_validation_using) about that but in a short it can be like this:

```
interface Positive {
}

class Amount {
   ...
   @DecimalMin(value = "0.01", message = "field.number.positive", groups=Positive.class)
   private BigDecimal value;  
}

// when you want to validate that value is positive
Set<ConstraintViolation<Order>> violations = validator.validate(order, Positive.class);

// when you don't want to validate that value is positive
Set<ConstraintViolation<MyNewEntity>> violations = validator.validate(myNewEntity);
```

Comment: Lets say there is a class Shipping.java where I have "Amount shippingcost;" as a member variable. Similarly I have Order.java which has "Amount orderCost;" as member variable. Shipping.java and Order.java has @Valid annotations over Amount member variable. In one case I want to allow negative also and in other I don't want to.  How do I achieve this with group?

Comment: Then there should be two separate validation calls for Shipping and for Order - one with group and second without (Default group) - same as in the example above. A group name can be whatever you like - it even can be like **OrderChecks** to specify that this constraint applies only for **Order** class, etc..

Comment: Is it possible that I can do this at runtime also

Comment: Could you give more context on that? Where is a place in your application code where an actual validation call is performed (i.e. validator.validate)? Is it controlled by you (then it's simple - just split to multiple calls) or by 3rd party API?